# How to get the current year from first week that started previous year

Tags: sql, oracle

If I run this code

```
Select
to_char(to_date('31-dec-2018'),'IW') as WEEK,
to_char(to_date('31-dec-2018'),'YYYY') AS YEAR
from dual
```

The output will be:

```
WEEK  YEAR

01    2018
```

I understand why but I wanted to get 2019 as this year is the first day of the ISO year was 12-31-2018. 
The desired output should be:

```
WEEK YEAR

01   2019
```

How can I accomplish this? Possible?

Comment: what if you add 1 day to your date before convertion to char?

Comment: Use `'IYYY'` instead of `'YYYY'`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks! not sure how I missed that!